# Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS crashing on battery with 40%

Tags: 16.04

I have a system 76 laptop and in the last week since updating it has crashed twice on me when using battery, once at 10% and once at 40%. I can't always use the cable so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Run the `power statistics` from `dash` and check your __battery capacity__.

Comment: What do you mean by "crashed" ? What (error or other message) do you see on the screen, or what exactly happens ?

Comment: I haven't run power statistics yet but I will when I get a chance. As for the crash no errors it the same effect as if the battery was pulled but it was sitting on a flat table and wasn't being touched at either of the moments it kicked off.